# How to get all option of atrributes color whose id is 92?

Tags: magento-1.9

How to get all option of attributes in magento, ?
I want to get all options of color attribute.

```
 $swatches = Mage::getStoreConfig('configswatches/general/swatch_attributes');

    echo "<pre>";print_R($swatches); die;

    output: 92,223,81,221,180
```

I got color attribute id = 92.. but how to load this id to get all options of color attributes.?

Answer (score 7):

You can try below code:

```
 $name='whatever_your_attribute_name';
 $attributeInfo = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')->setCodeFilter($name)->getFirstItem();
 $attributeId = $attributeInfo->getAttributeId();
 $attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
 $attributeOptions = $attribute ->getSource()->getAllOptions(false); 
 print_r($attributeOptions);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use below code to get all options of attribute with Id :

```
<?php
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'color');

if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($options);
    echo "</pre>";
}
?>
```

This will output/prints options Array like :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => 20
            [label] => Black
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => 27
            [label] => Blue
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [value] => 221
            [label] => Brown
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [value] => 17
            [label] => Charcoal
        )

    ....
```

**UPDATE** : For `key=>value` pairs, use `array_column` function,

> Just replace `print_r($options);` TO `print_r(array_column($options,
>   'label', 'value'));`

Comment: how to change these array in this format :  array(
     'key'=> 'Color',
     'value' => 'blue',
     'img' => 'blue.png',
     );  ... i mean how to add extra key through coding..

Comment: check updated answer